# Node.js nodemailer - Await new promise resolve error

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, nodemailer

I'm using node.js with nodemailer and I'm getting like this:

```
let mail = await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);
    } else {
        res.status(200).json({ "success": true, "message": 'Thank you for your registration! We\'ve sent you an email to confirm!' });
        resolve(mail);
    }
  });
});
```

It is sending out mails but I'm getting this error:

```
/home/project/controllers/signup.js:139
                        resolve(mail);
                                ^
ReferenceError: mail is not defined
    at transporter.sendMail (/home/project/controllers/signup.js:139:15)
    at transporter.send.args (/home/project/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js:226:21)
    at callback (/home/project/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/sendmail-transport/index.js:90:28)
    at ChildProcess.sendmail.once.code (/home/project/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/sendmail-transport/index.js:131:28)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Is this resolve(mail) not legitimate how I use it?

Comment: Yes mail is not defined, just as `let mail = mail`

Comment: ... but I thought I did by ... let mail = ... . I do I do it properly?

Comment: I have updated my last comment. The `resolve(mail)` make no sense anyway

Comment: Sorry I don't get it ... can you write a proper answer! Happy to accept it  ...

Comment: sorry but I cannot write a proper answer since I cannot understand what `resolve(mail)` means for you.

Comment: and what you expect the `mail` to be after the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let mail = await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);
    } else {
        res.status(200).json({ "success": true, "message": 'Thank you for your registration! We\'ve sent you an email to confirm!' });
        // change below
        resolve(info);
    }
  });
});
```

The above should work for you resolving with the `info` which you pass to the `sendMail` callback.

Answer (score 0):

in the else you are passing mail witch it not defined, just replace it with `info`

```js
else {
    res.status(200).json({
          success: true,
          message: 'Thank you for your registration! We\'ve sent you an email to confirm!'
     });
     resolve(info);
    }
```